# Using Cuda Object Linking with Cmake

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

Right now I am working on a project that uses the object linking capabilities of Cuda 5.  Since the project is starting to get complex, I wanted to switch to using cmake to compile the code.  However I can't seem to get object linking to work correctly for me.

I ended up creating a toy version of the project which gets the same kind of errors as the original project.  The toy project consists of a main file (TextureMain.cu) that calls a kernel function to run on the GPU.  In each GPU thread an instance of a user-defined class (TextureFunc) is referenced, where the class exists in a separate folder from the main file.  The class consists of a TextureFunc.cu and TextureFunc.h file in that folder.

Here are the CMakeList.txt files I am using:

In the project directory (contains src directory):

```
project(TextureMain)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=compute_20; -code=sm_20; -rdc=true; -lcudadevrt")
include_directories(src/TextureFunc)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
add_subdirectory(src/TextureFunc)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

In the src directory (contains TextureMain.cu and TextureFunc directory):

```
cuda_add_executable(TextureMain TextureMain.cu)
target_link_libraries(TextureMain TextureFunc)
install(TARGETS TextureMain DESTINATION bin)
```

In TextureFunc directory (contains TextureFunc.h and TextureFunc.cu):

```
cuda_add_library(TextureFunc TextureFunc.cu )
target_link_libraries(TextureFunc)
```

When I try to compile this code using the above CMakeList.txt files, I get the following error.

```
Linking CXX executable TextureMain
CMakeFiles/TextureMain.dir/./TextureMain_generated_TextureMain.cu.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_46_tmpxft_00004c15_00000000_6_TextureMain_cpp1_ii_texRef':
/tmp/tmpxft_00004c15_00000000-3_TextureMain.cudafe1.stub.c:2: undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_46_tmpxft_00004c15_00000000_6_TextureMain_cpp1_ii_texRef'
TextureFunc/libTextureFunc.a(TextureFunc_generated_TextureFunc.cu.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_46_tmpxft_00004bd8_00000000_6_TextureFunc_cpp1_ii_421ca072':
/tmp/tmpxft_00004bd8_00000000-3_TextureFunc.cudafe1.stub.c:8: undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_46_tmpxft_00004bd8_00000000_6_TextureFunc_cpp1_ii_421ca072'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/TextureMain] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/TextureMain.dir/all] Error 2
```

This is obviously a linking error, and it probably has to do with the way that I compile the code using cmake.  I think the flags for nvcc are right since I was able to compile this project using a Makefile with the same flags.  However, I'm not really sure what else I could be doing wrong.  I did notice that the error message references some non-existent .cpp files, but I don't know what to do with that.

Any advice that can be given would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using cmake version 2.8.8.

Comment: I don't know much about CUDA, but I see your `-lcudadevrt` in the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS. Is that the only library that is needed? I don't see it being applied to the linker command line, but that part may just be omitted.

Comment: @metal Yeah, that flag could be removed.  I spent some time searching for similar object linking problems earlier and for one problem it was suggested to add that flag.  The flag didn't actually help at all.  In any case I should probably remove it.

Comment: Well, it seems clear that you're missing a CUDA library (or have the wrong version?). Can you build it by hand to see what the proper command line options are and then compare that to what CMake is using?

Comment: Yes, I was able to build this using a Makefile with no errors, so I think the libraries are correct.  Changing the architecture version through the flags doesn't help either.  I've been trying to read through some of the scripts involved with CUDA cmake, but they aren't exactly user friendly.  The best that I can come up with so far, based on playing around with the Makefile, is that possibly cmake doesn't use the nvcc flags during the creation of the executable.  But I haven't found enough evidence to support this idea yet.

Comment: Does that -l flag make its way into your CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS variable? I'm saying, try to see what flags CMake is actually giving to the linker.

Comment: Looks like you are right, it does seem like those flags aren't being provided to the linker.  However once I add those flags, it gives me the error "c++: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch=compute_20’"  That tells me that CUDA isn't being used in the linking stage, since the error wouldn't occur if it was using nvcc.  For object linking in CUDA it's necessary to use nvcc. Object linking in CUDA is a relatively new thing (introduced with 5.0), so it's possible that cmake doesn't support it in the traditional sense.  In the very least there is no 'cuda_target_link_libraries' command.

Comment: (continued) I guess I'm going to have to look for a workaround somehow.

Comment: Did you try to add `-lcudadevrt` to `target_link_libraries(TextureMain TextureFunc)`?

Answer (score 5):

How about linking`${CUDA_LIBRARIES}` to whatever targets using `*.cu* files?

For example in your src directory you could try:

```
cuda_add_executable(TextureMain TextureMain.cu)
target_link_libraries(TextureMain TextureFunc ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS TextureMain DESTINATION bin)
```